# Input values not saved correctly in char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, fgets

What is wrong about the code? The values are not saved correctly in the arrays.

```
/*Deklaration und Initialisierung*/
float addition1=15, addition2=9, subtrahend1=5, subtrahend2=2;
double multiplikation1=9, multiplikation2=21, divident1=10, divident2=2;

const char passwort[]="15sdDv4";
const char username[]="KevKevin";
char tippedpasswort[8], tippedusername[8];
fflush(stdin);

printf("******************* Identifikation ************************\n\n Benutzername: ");

fgets(tippedusername,9,stdin); 
printf(" Passwort: ");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(tippedpasswort,9,stdin);

printf("Tippeduser: %s\nTippedpassword: %s\nUser: %s\nPassword: %s\n",tippedusername, tippedpasswort, username, passwort);
system("pause");

if (strcmp(tippedusername,username) != 0 || strcmp(tippedpasswort,passwort) != 0) {
    printf("\nMELDUNG: Passwort oder Benutzername leider falsch!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wäre euch sehr dankbar, wenn ihr eine Lösung für mich hättet, stell mich glaub ich ziemlich blöd an.

Comment: The post and the answer MUST be in english plz. Or i will have to vote to close the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I guess this is German language, right? Alas, I don't understand.*

**Point 1**

Referring `C11` standard, chapter 7.21.5.2, (emphasis mine)

> If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

`fflush(stdin);` is  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**Point 2**

I think you got the `fgets()` wrong. As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

> `fgets()` reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. *A terminating null byte (`\0`) is stored after the last character in the buffer.*

The *one less* is due to the requirement of putting the null, so, you should supply the exact allocated size, not `+1` to it.

You've got to change

```
fgets(tippedusername,9,stdin);
```

to

```
fgets(tippedusername,8,stdin);
```

or

```
fgets(tippedusername,sizeof tippedusername,stdin);
```

same for `tippedpasswort` case.